# How to show that boundary of unit ball is empty in ultrametric spaces

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

Let $(S,d)$ be an [ultrametric space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ultrametric_space#Formal_definition). According to wikipedia, any ball must have empty boundary. Why is this true? I am unable to prove this.

Comment: It suffices you show every open ball is also closed.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose that $x\in S$, and $y\notin S\setminus B(x,r)$, where $B(x,r)$ is the open ball of radius $r$ centred at $x$. I claim that $B(x,r)\cap B(y,r)=\varnothing$. To see this, suppose that $z\in B(x,r)\cap B(y,r)$. Then

$$d(x,y)=\max\{d(x,z),d(y,z)\}<r\;,$$

so $y\in B(x,r)$, contradicting the choice of $y$. Thus, every point of $S\setminus B(x,r)$ has an open nbhd disjoint from $B(x,r)$, so $\operatorname{cl}B(x,r)=B(x,r)$, and the boundary of $B(x,r)$ is empty.